# How to add 1 month to a DateTime variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Subscription model. In my subscriptions table I have a DateTime column called `expires_at`.

For example:

```
expires_at: "2013-07-03 08:00:26"
```

I need to add 30 days more. Which method do I need to use for this?

Comment: "1 month" and "30 days" is not the same. Adding 30 days to 2013-07-03 results in 2013-08-02, whereas adding 1 month results in 2013-08-03.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. It'll help you understand and use Stack Overflow. The more effort you put into researching and writing your question the better the answers will be.

Comment: Thank for you recommendation. I will  try  to write more relevant quastions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
=> object.expires_at + 1.month
=> Sat, 03 Aug 2013 08:00:26 +0000
```

Comment: or if it's an activerecord object you can just call: subscription.expires_at + 1.month

Comment: Similarly I think you can use DateTime advance method. eg. expires_at.advance(days: 30) [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/advance)

Comment: The link isn't applicable. The OP has a DateTime object and the linked page is talking about incrementing a Time object. They're not the same.